# Xml Parsing in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.atom on this site, I wrote the following code to retrieve the data.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string adresal = "http://" + txtAd.Text;
        WebResponse GelenCevap;
        WebRequest adresistegi = HttpWebRequest.Create(adresal);
        GelenCevap = adresistegi.GetResponse();
        StreamReader CevapOku = new StreamReader(GelenCevap.GetResponseStream());
        string KaynakKodlar = CevapOku.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); // Create an XML document object
        xmlDoc.Load("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.atom"); // Load the XML document from the specified file


        XmlNodeList depremler = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");

        foreach (XmlNode node in depremler)
        {


            var a = node.ChildNodes;
            foreach (XmlElement x in a)
            {

                ListBox1.Items.Add(x.InnerText);

            }

        }
```

}
In this way I get all the data in the ListBox.But I need to assign them to variable data line by line.How can I do? I would appreciate if you can help.

Also i need id,title, updated, georss:point,georss:elev variables.

Comment: Use LINQ to XML; it's far easier.  Also, make sure to use the XML namespace.

Answer (score 1):

First add an `Enrty` and `Category` class:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Updated { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string GPoint { get; set; }
    public string GElev { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
}
```

Then use LINQ to XML

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");

        List<Entry> entries = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("entry")
            select new Entry()
            {
                Id = (string) x.Element("id"),
                Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                Updated = (string)x.Element("updated"),
                Summary = (string)x.Element("summary"),
                GPoint = (string)x.Element("georss:point"),
                GElev = (string)x.Element("georss:elev"),
                Categories = (from c in x.Elements("category")
                                  select new Category
                                  {
                                      Label = (string)c.Attribute("label"),
                                      Term = (string)c.Attribute("term")
                                  }).ToList();
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried that code. I wrote this. But I couldn't get the results                            foreach (var x in entries)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(x.Id);
                //Console.WriteLine(x);
            }